# Twilio - How can I tell if a number can receive a text message?

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

I always relied on the "Carrier type" of "mobile" using the lookups API to determine if a number was able to receive a text message. This as served me well for several years.

I recently came across a lookup result as follows:

`CARRIER NAME  Enflick - 360 Networks - SVR
 CARRIER TYPE   voip`

It seems this belong to the textnow.com carrier that sells wifi only phone plans that allow texting. Because of this, it seems some "voip" carriers can receive texts.

Is there a way to determine which numbers should be eligible to receive texts using the Twilio lookups API or something similar? I'd hate to consider all voip carriers as texting eligible since that definitely isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the easiest way to check if a number can receive texts from Twilio is to try sending one. If the API responds with an error (likely [21612](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21612)) then you can't send messages to it.